# Snort Excluding Multiple Ports From ShellCode rules

Tags: snort

How can I specify mutliple ports to exclude from shellcode rules? I'm using the latest version of snort. I'm also interested in knowing which ports should generally be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

> portvar SHELLCODE_PORTS [!80,!25]

Works for me on snort 2.9.1.2.